# IsoDate and DateTime in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, datetime, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let us suppose that I want to query mongo on the dateTime. I have two C# variables representing  the start and the end date.

1) {20.10.2011 00:00:00}

2) {22.10.2011 00:00:00}

Now the BsonDateTime.Create(dateTime) transformed them to a BSON DateTime well too:

1) 2011-10-20T00:00:00  MongoDB.Bson.BsonDateTime

2) 2011-10-22T00:00:00  MongoDB.Bson.BsonDateTime

This is the code creating the dateTimes(_value is a string):

```
DateTime dateTime;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse(_value, out dateTime);
if (!parsed)
    throw new FormatException("Wrong format for a query param");
return BsonDateTime.Create(dateTime);
```

Then the next code builds the query:

```
private QueryComplete MakeQuery(string key, BsonValue value)
{
    if (_separatorType == ">=")
        return Query.GTE(key, value);
    if (_separatorType == "<=")
        return Query.LTE(key, value);
    return Query.EQ(key, value);
}
```

And i do get such a strange value in a query:

```
"Sessions.End" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2011-10-19T21:00:00Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2011-10-21T21:00:00Z") },
```

Well, I google ISODate  but haven't found any reason why it should be shifted. Is it OK?

Comment: You say you have two C# variables, but you haven't shown how they're initialized or even what type they are. I strongly suspect that's at the heart of things, but we can't tell without seeing the code. My guess is that you've created *local* DateTime values instead of UTC ones.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, added the code for dateTime creation, what is a UTC?

Comment: See my answer - follow the link for a description of UTC. Basically this is a time zone issue, I suspect...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `DateTime.TryParse` is giving you a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Local`... whereas the ISO date is always in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). I expect that some part of the MongoDB code is converting the local `DateTime` to one in UTC. It's largely *not* your fault - basically, [`DateTime` is a very confusing type](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

I suspect if you specify `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` in your parsing code, it will do what you expect.

(Shameless plug: my own project, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), makes all of this a lot simpler...)

Comment: Thank you very much Jon, it did help and this universal thing is really confusing, I'd like to get a better grip of datetimes

Comment: mongodb always store datatime as UTC, and mongodb c# driver converting to utc when save value and back to local when reading value from db.